# how control the time span of highlighting searched word when press "*" under evil in emacs?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

In evil mode, when press *, it will highlight the all the words the same under the cursor, but the highlight will disapper very soon. How can I control how long to keep the highlight? I am using prelude versiosn of emacs.

Comment: If it were I, I would look for a user option whose name starts with `evil-` (I assume that's the prefix) and contains `delay` or `max` or `time`. Or I would look in the code, to see what variable holds this time-period value. (I doubt that it is simply hard-coded.)

Comment: This type of question isn't about programming and thus is better suited for [emacs.stackexchange.com](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/). No need to do anything for this question if you're satisfied with the answers you get, but it may be something to keep in mind for future questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the highlights for two seconds:

```
(setq evil-flash-delay 2)
```

At the moment this doesn't seem to work with `(evil-select-search-module 'evil-search-module 'evil-search)`, which keeps the highlights until they are cleared by another search or with `:noh`. It's a bug, but unless you have that seach module line in your init file you won't see it.